# Can I parse a list in Python to separate out domain names from emails with multiple emails and delimiters in the same field?

Tags: python

I realize this may be a basic question, but if there is any help out there it would be greatly appreciated.

I need unique domain values and emails are

Current example field:

```
['email@domain.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com']
```

Needs to be:

```
['domain.com | domain2.com']
```

OR

```
['domain.com ; domain2.com']
```

if it's easier.

Thanks

Comment: Is the first example the current input? and example 2 is the expected output??

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your example a list of just one string? Or is it suppose to be a list with multiple strings? Or is it a text in a file? Is the output suppose to be just printed? Or is it suppose to be in a list of strings?

Comment: It looks like you just need a regular expression that matches `@` followed by all non-space characters.

Comment: `@\S+` will match that. Use it with `re.findall()`.

Comment: It is a list of multiple strings. Many strings with multiple emails in there. Output should also be a list of strings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
emails = ['email@domain.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com',
            'email@domain3.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com']

domains = list(set([email.split('@')[1] for email_word in emails
                    for email in email_word.split(' ; ')]))

print(domains)
```

Output :

```
['domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain.com']
```

Comment: i was about to post the same thing.Yea, using a set and splitting it will give the words. We could iterate thru one lesser

Answer (score 0):

I took a list as input.

```
emails  = ['email@domain.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com']
emails = emails.split(' ; ')
domains=set()
for i in emails:
    d = i.index('@')
    domains.add(i[d+1:])
print(domains)
```

Output will be a set `{'domain2.com', 'domain.com'}`

Comment: The list does not look like the way you have define. instead it looks like `['email@domain.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com']`

Comment: Correct. Thanks for looking out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this.

```
import re

x = ['email@domain.com ; email2@domain.com ; email3@domain2.com ; email4 ; email5@domain5.com']

#first remove all extra spaces. Then split based on ; 

x = re.sub(' ','',x[0]).split(';')

# For each string that has an email id with @, find the domain name
# set command will remove duplicates. Convert the set back to list and print the list

y = list(set([i[i.find('@')+1:] for i in x if '@' in i]))

#alternate code would be 
#y = list(set(i.split('@')[1] for i in x if '@' in i))

print(y)
```

This will output

```
['domain.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain5.com']
```

Comment: You could also do `y = list(set(i.split('@')[1] for i in x if '@' in i))` like @AnGG did